# How to remove features from geojson by mouse selection?

Tags: geojson, features

There are these unnecessary lines in my geojson:

[image]

You see, not all the borderline was deleted when I merged two countries.

Is there any way to quickly select and remove the features in a practical manner, because there's more than one case like this I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Deleted some of them by using Edit>"Remove Ring".

But there are still some which cannot be removed by this tool.
Is there such plugin available, that will remove lines that are irrelevant with the polygon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of GeoJSON and shapefiles is that they have no topology (the limit between 2 polygons is duplicate, digitized two times, see [Understanding Topology and Shapefiles](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0401/topo.html))

But there are other solutions than removing features by mouse:

1) you can use a GeoJSON format that encodes topology

see [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson)

2) If you use QGIS

The result is not correct with GeoJSON (or shapefiles)

[image]

[image]

But you only need a topological GIS where the common border exists once and is shared between the two areas as [GRASS GIS](http://grass.osgeo.org/). And GRASS GIS is integrated in the "Processing/Sextante" menu and you can use [v.dissolve](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.dissolve.html)
The process is (in a transparent manner):

1. the layer is imported and cleaned (topology) in GRASS GIS
2. the command v.dissolve is applied
3. the resulting layer is exported to QGIS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removed the others with the "Node Tool".
Clicking a node to make nodes editable (nodes get surrounded by square boxes), then making a rectangular selection and pressing Delete does the trick.

It still has some bugs, though. Sometimes a group of connected nodes have to be deleted at a specific order, because they cannot be deleted all at once. (QGIS Dufour 2.0.0)